# Using Multiple ActionScript 3 Classes

Tags: actionscript-3, class, package, document

I'm having trouble creating multiple AS3 classes, I've got my document class but can't get other classes.

Below is an example.

~Main.as

```
package {
    import uk.co.epickris.project.*;

    public class Main {
        public function Main() {
            trace('Main constructor.');
        }
    }
}
```

~/uk/co/epickris/project/Example.as

```
package uk.co.epickris.project {
    public class Example {
        public function Example() {
            trace('Example constructor.');
        }
    }
}
```

After running my flash project, I see the main constructor, but no the example constructor, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong if anything, any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `Example` class by creating an instance of it within the document class.

```
package
{
    import uk.co.epickris.project.*;

    public class Main
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            trace('Main constructor.');

            // We're creating an instance of the Example class here.
            var eg:Example = new Example();
        }
    }
}
```

Classes do not automatically have their constructor called when they are imported at the top of a class - instances of classes need to be created with the `new` keyword.

When the `new` keyword is used to create an instance, the constructor (defined by creating a function with the same name as the class) will be called as well.

Your document class is the only class in your case that is created and has its constructor called automatically, as that is the nature of a document class.

---

Please take some time to read this article about the basics of Object-oriented programming in AS3:
[Introduction to OOP](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix/)

Comment: Thanks, I've done that and now I'm getting an error. `1180: Call to possible undefined method Example.`

Comment: @KristianMatthews Ensure that `Main.as` is in the same directory as the folder `uk` (the folder that contains your other directories/classes).

Comment: The `Main.as` and `uk` folder are in the some folder.

Comment: @KristianMatthews Odd - maybe give a less complicated folder structure a try (take Example.as and put it into the `package uk` rather than `uk.co.epickris.project`). I believe there are issues with lengthy package names.

Comment: Okay, then would I name the package `package uk` or `package uk.Example`?

Comment: @KristianMatthews The package statement will be `package uk` and the import statement will be `import uk.Example`

Comment: I created a new file and it seems to work with no problems with that with the same setup as above, so not sure what went wrong honestly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KristianMatthews No worries, I've added a link that I think you should have a thorough look over to the bottom of my answer. It should help you out significantly.